# MVC4 Navigation Property not saving

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, navigation-properties

I have created an MVC4 CodeFirst app with a parent model class with a public virtual child navigation property.

```
public class ParentObject
    {
        [Key]
        public int ParentItemId { get; set; }
        public string ParentItemName { get; set; }

        public virtual ChildItem childItem { get; set; }
    }

public class ChildItem
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public String ItemDescription { get; set; }
    public string SomeOtherText { get; set; }
}
```

I created an editor template for my Child item and it creates the expected drop down on the Edit page.

When I select a new value in the DropDownList and click save the newly selected value is passed back to the controller.

```
  [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(ParentObject parentobject)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(parentobject).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(parentobject);
    }
```

and the db.SaveChanges(); line is executed without error.

Why is the new value not saved in the childItem_ItemId field?